# SearchBar doesnt have 'X' button on right hand side

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uisearchbar

As you can see my SearchBar doesn't have an 'X' button, which is normally at the right hand side of the SearchBar.
I only have the issue using Android, iOS has an X and a cancel button.
Do I need to add a tag in or what am I doing wrong?

[image]

```
 <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="BottleShop.Views.Products">
        <NavigationPage.TitleView>
            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <SearchBar x:Name="Search" TextColor="Black" BackgroundColor="Purple" TextChanged="Searc_TextChanged" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Placeholder="Search..." PlaceholderColor="Gray" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
            <ToolbarItem Name="CartImage" Icon="ShoppingCart.png" Priority="0" Order="Primary" Activated="Clicked"/>
            <ToolbarItem Text="{Binding NoItemsInShoppingCart}" Priority="0" Activated="Clicked" Order="Primary"/>
        </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

        <ContentPage.Content>
```

Xamarin.Forms v5.0.0.2012

Comment: If no one comes up with a suggestion, then please download [SearchBar demo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-searchbardemos/) and build/run on android. Does 'X' show in that demo?  Maybe you can figure out what is different in it, that works.

Comment: yeah great idea. thanks for the reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove

> NavigationPage.TitleView

Or

> StackLayout BackgroundColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
> VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal"

If the SearchBar surrounded by **NavigationPage.TitleView** and **StackLayout**, the 'X' button will disappear. Remove anyone of them can solve the problem.

[image]